# Update Index Settings Analyzer in Java

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

I want to update filter in my analyzer, so saw this **UpdateSettingsRequestBuilder** but there we need to pass the whole updated settings string. Can we just pass the updated filter like in Elastic?

My Index Settings::

```
"settings": {
    "number_of_shards": "3",
    "index.mapping.total_fields.limit": 10000,
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "minimal_english": {
          "type": "stemmer",
          "language": "minimal_english"
        },
      "synonym_graph": {
      "type": "synonym_graph",
      "updateable": "true"
    }
 }
}
}
```

Elastic query:

```
PUT /test_index2/_settings
{
  "analysis" : {
    "filter": {
        "synonym_graph": {
           "type": "synonym_graph",
            "updateable": "true",
            "synonyms": ["i-phone, i phone => iphone"]
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a way we can pass just this filter as in elastic to update the filter in java.

Answer (score 0):

Updating an index settings with the put settings API is currently not possible directly in Spring Data Elasticsearch API.

You can create such a request by yourself and send it to Elasticsearch using the `ElasticsearchTemplate.execute()` method:

```java
ElasticsearchTemplate restTemplate; // injected 

// setup the request
UpdateSettingsRequest updateSettingsRequest = new UpdateSettingsRequest();

AcknowledgedResponse response = restTemplate.execute(client ->
    client.indices().putSettings(updateSettingsRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT));
```

Comment: So here in UpdateSettingsRequest we have pass the whole analysis, is there a way that I can send only the required field( which is synonym here) and it's updated value

Comment: I can't tell , I did not try this out. Looking at the the docs (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-update-settings.html) and at the code of `UpdateSettingsRequest` you will probably have to call `UpdateSettingsRequestBuilder.setPreserveExisting(true)`. I suggest you write a small app theta first writes a setting, then update this and after that readi it again and check.